# COUNTIF with table filtering, or how does the SUMPRODUCT/SUBTOTAL/OFFSET combination actually work?

Tags: filter, count, excel-formula, subtotal, walkthrough

Given the following Excel table:

```
+---+--------+----+----+
|   | A      | B  | C  |
+---+--------+----+----+
| 1 | Filter | V1 | V2 | <-- header row of the table, with filtering option
+---+--------+----+----+
| 2 | F1     | x  | x  |
| 3 | F2     | x  | y  |
| 4 | F1     | x  | y  |
+---+--------+----+----+
```

I need to count the number of `x` in `V1` and `V2` columns:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:C4, "x")
```

This works and returns `4`. Now, if I filter the table so that the column `Filter` only contains `F1` values:

```
+---+--------+----+----+
|   | A      | B  | C  |
+---+--------+----+----+
| 1 | Filter | V1 | V2 | <-- header row of the table, with filtering option
+---+--------+----+----+
| 2 | F1     | x  | x  |
| 4 | F1     | x  | y  |
+---+--------+----+----+.
```

The first formula still returns `4`. I already found how to improve it so that is takes into account the possible filters (this solution can easily be found on the Internet):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C4="x") * SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(B2:C4, ROW(B2:C4) - MIN(ROW(B2:C4)), 0, 1, 1)))
```

This returns `3` for the second case, as expected. The question is: how does it work? Is anyone able to give me a detailed walkthrough of the second formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets have a look at SUMPRODUCT:
SUMPRODUCT expect its arguments as arrays (matrices). So

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C4="x"))`

takes an array of `{TRUE,TRUE;TRUE,FALSE;TRUE,FALSE}` depending on if `(B2:C4="x")`.

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C4="x")*1)`

would get the boolean values in numeric context as `{1,1;1,0;1,0}`. Now SUMPRODUCT will SUM this array and get 4.

`=SUBTOTAL(3, B2:C4)` will only count if the single cell in `B2:C4` is not invisible because it is filtered out. So it gets 6 when unfiltered but 4 for example, if F2 is filtered out.

`{=OFFSET(B2:C4, ROW(B2:C4) - MIN(ROW(B2:C4)), 0, 1, 1)}` used in array context gets `{=OFFSET(B2:C4, {2;3;4} - 2, 0, 1, 1)}`  = `{=OFFSET(B2:C4, {0;1;2}, 0, 1, 1)}` which takes `B2:C4` moved `{0;1;2}` rows downwards, ever 0 columns sidewards, ever in height 1 and width 1 which results in `{B2;B3;B4}`

So we have with SUBTOTAL

`{=SUBTOTAL(3, {B2;B3;B4})}` which only counts 1 if `{B2;B3;B4}` is not filtered out..

So the result of the SUBTOTAL when F2 (B3) is filtered out is: `{1;0;1}`.

Within the SUMPRODUCT and out filtered row 3 we have:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C4="x")*{1;0;1})`

which is `{TRUE,TRUE;TRUE,FALSE;TRUE,FALSE} * {1;0;1}`  =  `{1,1;0,0;1,0}` which sums to 3.

---

To simplify this I would use

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C4="X")*SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT("A"&ROW(2:4))))`

which works the same way except that the `INDIRECT` results in `{A2;A3;A4}` and, because the "A" is a fixed text string, you have to change the formula if you will insert columns before column A.

This is not necessary with the `OFFSET` variant because there all arguments are cell references which updates automatically when a column will be inserted.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. There is still one point that isn't very clear to me: why does `{=OFFSET(B2:C4, {0;1;2}, 0, 1, 1)}` results in `{B2;B3;B4}`? What happens when we give a matrix as first `OFFSET` argument (`B2:C4`) rather than a single value?

Comment: Hm, this is not the point. If you offset `B2:C4` one row downwards, you get `B3:C5`. But in the used OFFSET formula height and width are ever 1. See my supplement in the answer.